# How to search for specific Git log with specific number as commit message

Tags: git

I have 2 different commit messages. for example one commit message is 2000.11 and other commit message is 2000.115.
When i am trying to get the log details of the commit message 2000.11, using the command 
***git log --grep=2000.11***, 
it is taking the other commit message i.e 2000.115 also.

How do I search for the specific commit message? 
 or does git have the limitation of taking only 2 decimal points and after that what ever is commits with 3rd decimal point will be included in the git log results ?

Comment: `git log --all --grep='2000.11'`, it should work.

Comment: No, it is still showing both the commit id's

Comment: What do you mean by _commit id_? Commits in Git are usually referred by SHA1: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects Your numbers are not valid SHA1 strings.

Comment: I meant commit message. i will update the text.

Comment: What's the exact output of `git log --grep=2000.11`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to match the exact commit message.

***git log --all --grep="\<2000.11\>"***

or

***git log --grep="\<2000.11\>"***

This will match the whole string "2000.11" in the commit message.

Comment: You should have posted your full output at first. It really matters!

Answer (score 0):

`git log --all --grep='2000.11 '`

Depending on how the commit id is structured, maybe adding a space at the end will help.

Comment: No, the result is empty now.

Comment: Where is the "2000.11" part located, in the commit message?

Comment: in the starting itself like id #2000.11. it seems that this can be tweaked by putting braces around this message. but I was looking for a more specific expression commit message matching.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$` at tail of regexp.

```
git log --all --grep='2000.11$'
```

Comment: No, the result is still empty.